# How to find the logs of my file implementation when Openshift can not find the server?

Tags: openshift, web-deployment

I hope this is not a silly question but I have not found any documentation answering this silly question, if it is:

I tried to implement my website using OpenShift, which is the platform as a service used by the university. But as you can see [in the link](http://qmulpython35-moodbot.apps.devcloud.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/), it seems that the server was not launched. I had added the GitHub link. However, I can not find the records. Do you know where they are?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: FYI. This is not the latest OpenShift Origin 3.X, but OpenShift 2.X. So is quite old version of OpenShift.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Oh you're the one that wrote OpenShift for Developers ! Thank for the information. I'm reading your book while discovering OpenShift. I didn't that was an old version although I suspected it. Anyway, that's what my university gave me to deploy their website. Do you know where I might find some quick and useful documentation ? Because so far I'm quite lost, I even tried to run the small Node applcation given in one of OpenShift tutorial using the Node 0.10 rather than their app but there was still this error 401

Comment: I don't think there is any online docs any more for OpenShift 2.X. If you email me at my firstname.lastname at gmail.com then I can send you PDF of older Getting Started with OpenShift book. This was a free eBook download as well, but with it being for OpenShift 2.X, it seems to have gone as well and can't be downloaded either.

Comment: I've temporarily resurrected the v2 developer center for you, https://devcenter-web-properties-openshift.e203.evg.openshiftapps.com/managing-your-applications/log-files.html. I hope this helps! The docs are still kicking around as well, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/index.html.

Comment: @WillGordon Thank you ! Do I have to assume that my university is using very old servers ? I am tring to follow the docs as well that books. With the first one I arrived [at step 2.3, basic administration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-Basic_Administration.html) which leads me to a message `We will not be accepting new users onto the OpenShift Online (v2) platform.` whereas the second lead me to a [security connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060578/how-configure-the-client-to-work-with-the-openshift-online-account)

Comment: You are unfortunately using _very_ old servers. Which is not ideal, especially because the containerized world is moving fast, as did OpenShift. The newest version is completely rewritten and is based on Docker and Kubernetes. For your own experience, I encourage you to check out [OpenShift Online](https://manage.openshift.com) or the [OpenShift Learning platform](https://learn.openshift.com).